# How to fetch Approver name after Approval stage Comala API

Tags: rest, api, workflow, confluence

How to fetch users who approved Confluence page with Simple Comala Workflow using Comala Rest API?

Before Approval, after assigning to users for approval:

```
curl -k -X GET -u <username> -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -H 'Accept: application/json' http://<confluence-url>/rest/cw/1/content/<page-id>/status?expand=state,states,approvals,actions,tasks | python -mjson.tool
```

Response:

```
{
    "actions": [
        {
            "actions": [
                "approve",
                "reject",
                "assign",
                "unassign"
            ],
            "involvedUsers": [
                {
                    "fullName": "minzey",
                    "name": "emp_id",
                    "pictureUrl": "/images/icons/profilepics/default.png",
                    "shortName": "minzey"
                },
                {
                    "fullName": "second user",
                    "name": "emp_id",
                    "pictureUrl": "/images/icons/profilepics/default.png",
                    "shortName": "second user"
                }
            ],
            "name": "Review",
            "requiresComment": false,
            "shortName": "Review",
            "type": "approval"
        }
    ],
    "approvals": [
        {
            "approvers": [
                {
                    "approved": false,
                    "rejected": false,
                    "user": {
                        "fullName": "second user",
                        "name": "emp_id",
                        "pictureUrl": "/images/icons/profilepics/default.png",
                        "shortName": "second user"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "approved": false,
                    "rejected": false,
                    "user": {
                        "fullName": "minzey",
                        "name": "emp_id",
                        "pictureUrl": "/images/icons/profilepics/default.png",
                        "shortName": "minzey"
                    }
                }
            ],
            "description": "Requires approval from second user and minzey",
            "filterExcludedUsers": [],
            "filterGroups": [],
            "filterUsers": [],
            "name": "Review",
            "shortName": "RE"
        }
    ],
    "expand": "",
    "messages": [],
    "state": {
        "colour": "#FFAB00",
        "final": false,
        "initial": false,
        "name": "In Progress"
    },
    "states": [
        {
            "approvals": [
                {
                    "approvers": {
                        "minimum": "*"
                    },
                    "name": "Review"
                }
            ],
            "colour": "#FFAB00",
            "name": "In Progress",
            "taskable": true,
            "transitions": {
                "approved": "Approved"
            }
        },
        {
            "colour": "#14892c",
            "final": true,
            "name": "Approved",
            "transitions": {
                "updated": "In Progress"
            }
        }
    ],
    "tasks": [],
    "workflowName": "Simple approval workflow"
}
```

After both approvals, response:

```
{
    "actions": [],
    "approvals": [],
    "expand": "",
    "messages": [],
    "publishedState": {
        "colour": "#14892c",
        "final": true,
        "initial": false,
        "name": "Approved"
    },
    "state": {
        "colour": "#14892c",
        "final": true,
        "initial": false,
        "name": "Approved"
    },
    "states": [
        {
            "approvals": [
                {
                    "approvers": {
                        "minimum": "*"
                    },
                    "name": "Review"
                }
            ],
            "colour": "#FFAB00",
            "name": "In Progress",
            "taskable": true,
            "transitions": {
                "approved": "Approved"
            }
        },
        {
            "colour": "#14892c",
            "final": true,
            "name": "Approved",
            "transitions": {
                "updated": "In Progress"
            }
        }
    ],
    "tasks": [],
    "workflowName": "Simple approval workflow"
}
```

Information in response.states.approvals.approvers is now empty. How do i populate this field with approver names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The *Comala Workflows* REST API only provides the information on the actual status of the workflow. You have to interpret the "approvers" information as "pending approvers", so you won't retrieve an approver's information once their approval is applied.
You can get more information at:

https://comalatech.bitbucket.io/comala-workflows/5.3.0/restapi/json_ContentWorkflowResponse.html

Note that the list of approvals refers to "available approvals in the current state". 
Approvers (https://comalatech.bitbucket.io/comala-workflows/5.3.0/restapi/json_Approvers.html) are shown as one of the parameters of the approvals.